# How to show Days in Case in Drupal Views?

Tags: civicase, drupal-views, dates

Trying to create a Drupal View that shows total number of days in a case.

There are two methods I'm considering:

First, I imagine if I could turn the case start date and end date into "Days Ago" within the view I could perform a math calculation of [end_date]-[start_date] to get the number.

The other method I thought may work would be to create an aggregate table through views that displayed a daily case load.  For example, on 1.1.15 list these 5 people that have ongoing cases.  On 1.2.15 list these 5 people that have an open case.  From there, I could group by contact name and count.

Anyone have any ideas or done something similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it!

**In Drupal added the Unix Timestamp format:**
Administration/Regional and Language/Formats/Add Format.
For the string I put in `U`.
Added the Date Type Unix Timestamp

**In the View:**
Added the Start and End Date fields.
Under Date Format selected the Unix Timestamp type I just created.
Added a Math Expression field with the expression `(([end_date]-[start_date])/86400)` since there are 86400 seconds in a day.